# Create a mosaic from images with no spatial reference system in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, image-mosaic

I have 10 raster images (.tif format) with no spatial reference system (SRS). Is it possible to mosaic them?

Comment: Please DO NOT use ALL CAPS in your titles.  https://www.google.com/search?q=arcgis+mosaic+tiff suggests that you will be able to do this.  What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried the "Create Raster Dataset" from the Data Management tools. But the images are not matched correctly. I think this is because there is a missing projection in my original images.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Mosaicking doesn't operate in a vacuum. If the images are not georefereced and in the same coordinate system, you still have some prep work to do.

Comment: What do you mean prep work? Maybe you can recommend any program which can create a mosaic by matching same point of 2 images?

Comment: The [Help] states that a question is *too broad* if your question can be answered by a book. In this case, it's several chapters, but still too broad. Software recommendation requests are closed as *opinion-based*, so I recommend you avoid that here. You have the tools needed to accomplish your goal; you just need to do some basic research on image management,  georeferencing, and mosaicking.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must make sure all 10 images are referenced one by one the most accurate way. After that you should visually check if it's all right. If it seems fine just then you should Mosaic Raster.
I suppose you might get errors if accidentally one ore more blank spots are created after georeferencing.

P. S. Maybe it is worth to have separate 10 images. And work with them as a group of elements in the Table Of Contents. In that case they are slightly smaller (by size, not dimensions). Zooming & panning works faster as well.

[image: Example]